# A possible domain for the Log function

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

When I choose some usual branch of the function(like $\mathbb{C}$ minus $0$ and the negative real axis), I know that $log(z) = log|z| + $$i$ $arg(z)$.

If I define the domain of the log, as a different but simply conected region like A, does the formula that I stated before to calculate log keeps making sense?
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this tristam needham?

Comment: @Buraian No, it's from 'Basic Complex Analysis' of Marsden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as, for each $z\in A$, you take the appropriate argument of $z$. That is, there is a function $\operatorname{arg}_A\colon A\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ such that:

1. For each $z\in A$, $\operatorname{arg}_A(z)$ is an argument of $z$.
2. The function $\operatorname{arg}_A$ is continuous.
3. For each $z\in A$, $\log z=\log|z|+\operatorname{arg}_A(z)$.

Note that then, in the set $A$ from your picture (which intersects $(0,\infty)$ in two distinct intervals), the positive reals $z$ closer to $0$ will give a certain value of $\operatorname{arg}_A(z)$, whereas those from the segment further away from $0$ will have *another* value of $\operatorname{arg}_A(z)$.